# Fade in Fade out inside the bar using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created the expand and collapse bar with text effect as fadein fadeout. But that effect is not triggered properly whenever i refresh the page it works perfect when i close the bar after 2,3 seconds that bar expand and shows the message. If you see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tJRsB/18/)

You can see what i was talking about exactly. I am not sure how i hide the message if it is in close mode and display the message if it is in expand mode. Any suggestion would be great.

```
.message_after_login {display: none;
                                  text-align: center;
                                  color:white;
                                  font-size:24px;
                                  position: relative;
                                  left:0px;
                                  right:0px;

            }
```

Thanks,
vicky

Comment: Your code is really messy and unreadable

Comment: @undefined I don't mean the indenting I mean the logic behind the code.

Comment: @Itay I see, I think caching the objects and using `$` instead of `jQuery` could make it more readable.

Comment: @undefined I edited my fiddle with $ instead of jQuery.

Comment: Please read http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx you are not making much sense, hard to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have this:

```
function shownextmessage() {
    ++message_index;
    message.eq(message_index % message.length)
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .delay(2000)
        .fadeOut(2000, shownextmessage);
 }
```

You are selecting the text to animate using a modulo in the $.eq... and once the fadeOut finishes, you relaunch that function... So it runs in loops passing 1 and 2 and 1 and 2 ... to message.eq hence why the texts keep rolling...

Since your question actually does not include a question nor says what you'd like to achieve I can only explain why what happens is happening and cannot provide with a solution.

Comment: Thanks for heads up. I want to show the fade in and fade out effect for expand alone not for close. Is it possible to achieve this ?

Comment: What is "Expend" and "Close" for you?

Comment: If you see the demo to expand the bar and close the bar as button in right side of the result.